# Unable to apt-get with jessie-backports value

Tags: debian, apt, backports

I'm trying to run the following command

```
sudo apt-get install -t jessie-backports openjdk-8-jre-headless
```

with the `jessie-backports` value, but receive the following error when I run the command

```
E: The value 'jessie-backports' is invalid for APT::Default-Release as such a release is not available in the sources
```

However I've added the backports repository to my `source.list` file under `/etc/apt/source.list`

I used the line for Debian from this [webpage](https://backports.debian.org/Instructions/).

My `source.list` file has the following repositories:

[image: Source list file]

What am I missing or doing incorrectly? Thanks.

Comment: Did you run `apt-get update` after adding the backports entry? Also, it should be `/etc/apt/sources.list`, not `/etc/apt/source.list`

Comment: It would be nice if you just copy the text from your terminal window into the question instead of using an image.

Comment: @RalfFriedl, I'm accessing the OS through a ESXi's web client, or I would have.

Comment: @maulinglawns, good catch on the file name. It was the wrong one. When I run `apt-get update` now, I get an error message stating `W: Failed to fetch http:...`. I can navigate to the site, but I can't ping it from the terminal. I'll have to do some research. @maulinglwans, if you want to submit that as the answer, I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: Please copy the entire error message, and put it in the question (as an edit) rather then in a comment, and do it as text not a picture (even if it means you have to type it, then just make sure to avoid typos), for one reason: pictures can't be searched.

Comment: You also have an error in the second to last line, it shouldn't be ht*pp*redir but httpredir.

Comment: @Henrik, the typo `htppredir` isn’t relevant to calling `apt-get` with `jessie-backports`. I will be sure to include text instead of images in future posts.

Comment: @cwanjt No problem. Comment submitted as an aswer. I hope you can debug the network issues from here on.

Comment: Please tell us version of Debian.

Comment: I didn't mean to imply that the typo in any way had anything to do with your problem, just wanted to help you by pointing it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The apt sources should be in:

```
/etc/apt/sources.list
```

Not, as in your screenshot: `/etc/apt/source.list`
Note the missing '`s`' in `sources`

So, for starters, rename with:

```
mv -i /etc/apt/source.list /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Then try an `apt-get update` and debug from there.

Comment: Just renaming like that would overwrite the existing `sources.list` losing any source in that not in he badly named version. As apt in most cases does a good job of selecting packages when they are available from more than one repo, it will probably be safer to just append the contents of the badly named version with something like `cat  /etc/apt/source.list >> /etc/apt/sources.list` (and then clean up when the system is working).

Comment: Good point @Henrik. Added the `-i` switch to `mv` in the answer to prevent this.

Answer (score -3):

Just upgrade the whole distro to latest debian.

Comment: Under some circumstances, this may be either impossible or have undesirable consequences.  The backports are there for a reason.